# How to design an iOS app which runs only in landscape mode in ipad and portrait in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, storyboard, orientation

I am new to iOS development.I am making an app which runs on iPad and iPhone.I am using universal storyboard.I want the phone to work only in portrait mode and iPad to work only in landscape mode.How to do the design for ipad in landscape?Can we rotate the storyboard and design?Also,let me know how to lock the interface orientation lock for iPad.Thank you in advance.I need the objective-C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Info.Plist file,add two rows as shown in the picture.Uncheck all the orientations in the

```
Target--->General--->Deployment info.
```

[image: How to design an ios app which works only in landscape mode in ipad?]

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to create two different storyboard. one for iphone and one for ipad.

To design in landscape / portrait you need to set below settings.

First go to your storyboard.
Select viewController -> Attribute inspector -> Simulated Metrics -> Orientation -> Change to landscape / portrait.

In Your Target set Device Orientation to Landscape Left and Landscape Right for your iPad and portrait for iphone.

Also tell me are you using navigation controller in your storyboard ???

Please Vote if you find useful.

Comment: Two different storyboards??I am using universal storyboard,So is there some way by which i can restrict the orientation through code.

Comment: Yes 2 storyboards because the position, constraints, auto layouts of controls are different in portrait and in landscape and if you only use one single storyboard you will have difficulty in maintaing the design and also there will be issues in auto layouts and constraints. So it is better to have 2 different storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subclass for your view controllers where you override this method below. This will enable Landscape orientation for iPad and Portrait for iPhone.

I create a subclass of UIViewController with this method implemented inside the subclass and then I'll subclass MySubclassViewController throughout the project.

```
// iOS6+
// MySubclassViewController.m
@interface MySubclassViewController : UIViewController
@end

/*  Doc:
    This method is only called if the view controller's 
    shouldAutorotate method returns YES.
 */
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        /* iPad device */
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }else{
        /* iPhone device */
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your view controller, arrange the return types accordingly, I don't have access to my old codes now.

```
-(BOOL)isPad
{
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    return UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
#endif
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if([self isPad]){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else{
        return SOMETHING_ELSE;
    }
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if([self isPad]){
        return return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
    else{
        return SOMETHING_ELSE;
    }
}
```